# how to make textfield open my custom datepicker material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have textField and I want when user click on the textfield my Custom datepicker open, this is my textfield :

```
<TextField
    InputLabelProps={{
        classes: {
            root: classes.cssLabel,
            focused: classes.cssFocused
        }
    }}
    InputProps={{
        classes:{underline: classes.underline},
        endAdornment: (
            <DatePicker width='120px' id='cfhPassDateFrom'
                onChange={(value) => { let row = this.state.searchData; row['cfhPassDateFrom'] = value; this.setState({ searchData: row }); }} />
        )
    }} 
    id="cfhPassDateFrom" label='ارجاع از تاریخ' type="text" fullWidth 
    onChange={(value) => { let row = this.state.searchData; row['cfhPassDateFrom'] = value; this.setState({ searchData: row }); }} />
```

but its working like this

- see the white box! I want to get rid of that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this apporach,

Set a `open` props to `DateField` and control through the state. Capture the click hanler of `TextField` and update the `isOpen`. Specify `onChange` handler based on your use case (currently i didn't set the onChange handler)

```
const DateContainer = () => {
  // const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        // InputLabelProps={{
        //     classes: {
        //         root: classes.cssLabel,
        //         focused: classes.cssFocused
        //     }
        // }}
        onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
        InputProps={{
          // classes:{underline: classes.underline},
          endAdornment: (
            <DatePicker
              width="120px"
              onChange={(value) => {}}
              id="cfhPassDateFrom"
              open={isOpen}
            />
          )
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-pickers-open-modal-click-on-text-forked-xnokn?file=/index.js

Comment: @sarun_UK tnx man, just one thing, is ther any way to open this datePicker tunder the textfield?

Comment: this is the straight forward approach. Does this work for you ?

Comment: @sarun_UK I prefer that if it's possible